# Resilience4J threads stuck in Running state forever

Tags: java, multithreading, jvisualvm, resilience4j

I forked the [spring-boot2-demo](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo) repo to [this](https://github.com/asthinasthi/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo)

Did these changes :

BackendBController.java

```
@GetMapping("futureTimeout")
public String futureTimeout(){
    for(int i=0; i< 1000; i++){
        executeAsyncWithFallback(this::timeout, this::fallback);
    }
    return "Something";
}
```

I invoked the `/futureTimeout` endpoint in BackedBController

### I see this in JVisualVM

[image]

I am trying to understand if this the expected behavior i.e. Once the job is complete will threads remain active? Shouldn't they be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

`corePoolSize` number of threads will always be active once the threadpool is created. It's only the excess `maximumPoolSize-corePoolSize` that will be created & destroyed after completion of the tasks.